# Wordpress - add custom tinymce shortcode in another text editor and not only classic editor

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, shortcode

Here my problem: I have some different text area (isn't Wordpress Classic Editor, but many Wysiwyg editor from Visual Composer plugin). My theme include in the tinymce some shortcodes. But when I want to insert shortcode in a specific textarea, the shortcode appears in the classic editor everytime.
So I would try to say in the code "put the code in the text box on which I want to insert the shortcode and not in the traditional publisher".
Here my code I think the solution could be :

```
    addWithPopup: function(ed, title, id) {
        ed.add({
            title: title,
            onclick: function() {
                tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('FreshShortcodesPopup', false, {
                    title: title,
                    identifier: id
                });
            }
        });
    },
```

Hope you can help me...
Regards.
math.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `tinyMCE.activeEditor` to address the editor. `tinyMCE.activeEditor` won't change unless the user explicitly clicks into another editor. Another trap is that `tinyMCE.activeEditor` is not initialized unless the an editor is clicked at all.
It is better to address the editor instance using its id:

```
tinymce.get('your_editor_id').execCommand(...
```

UPDATE: what about

```
        onclick: function(ed) {
           console.log('ed:',ed);
           ed.execCommand('FreshShortcodesPopup', false, {
                title: title,
                identifier: id
            });
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, and sorry for my question, but how can I find the editor_id ?

Comment: there is a source html element for which each editor gets inialized (in most cases a textarea) - the editor gets the same id

Comment: I tried to with get(0), 1, 2 but already in the main editor. With 3, 4 nothing works. I found this tinyMCE.get('wysiwyg-acf-field-shortcode_area-519c9a9e042ec') but the "pop up" window to add shortcode doesn't appear.

Comment: what do you get as output?

Comment: To be honnest I don't know. TinyMCE included with a wordpress theme I bought. I found only a file called tinymce.js

Comment: what do you get in your console, what is ed ?

Comment: I feel a bit silly because I'm not an expert coder. Is that I can send you an email with access to the site and send the file? We can discuss compensation because it is important and urgent that I find a compromise on this issue.

Comment: if you had 20 reputation we could use the chat

Comment: I have 13 ;-) I send you an e-mail.